# how to process pop3 emails from gmail server in mule anypoint studio

Tags: java, mule, pop3, email-processing

I am trying to make an application in mule anypoint studio 7 which receives pop3 emails from the server of a gmail acocunt using the email connector. The type of object or the email body content that I receive when I list emails from a POP3 server using the connector varies when I send emails from outlook & gmail.

Can someone help me to get the text email body when i send emails from different accounts to my gmail account.

Comment: Could you share us your progress?

Comment: What are the types of bodies that you are receiving?